# React Native MQTT Module `url` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: react-native, mqtt

I want to explore this project https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js within the React Native environment.  So I did this:

```
react-native init myproject
npm install --save mqtt
```

Then I pasted this sample code from the mqttjs into my App.js a bit after the "Welcome to React Native" component.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```

But when I run `react-native run-android`, I get a compilation error with a message like

> Module `url` does not exist in the Haste module map

I tried replacing `mqtt://test.mosquitto.org` with a url to my own mosquitto broker with some of these values: `mqtt://192.168.0.20`, `tcp://192.168.0.20`, `192.168.0.20`.  But all these still generated the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i have the same error :(

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by explicitly installing the url module:

```
npm install url
```